# numpys argsort, sorting column based on another one

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to sort the array `a` based on the first column:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[  1.50000000e+03,   1.68693009e-01],
   [  5.00000000e+02,   1.26512097e-01],
   [  1.50000000e+03,   1.68338907e-01],
   [  5.00000000e+02,   1.22073944e-01],
   [  5.00000000e+02,   1.31257631e-01],
   [  1.50000000e+03,   1.72864036e-01],
   [  1.50000000e+03,   1.70665459e-01],
   [  5.00000000e+02,   1.32951654e-01],
   [  1.00000000e+03,   1.49342105e-01]])
sort = a.T.argsort(0)
b = a[sort]
print(b)
```

gives me:

```
[[[  5.00000000e+02   1.26512097e-01]
[  5.00000000e+02   1.26512097e-01]
[  5.00000000e+02   1.26512097e-01]
[  5.00000000e+02   1.26512097e-01]
[  5.00000000e+02   1.26512097e-01]
[  5.00000000e+02   1.26512097e-01]
[  5.00000000e+02   1.26512097e-01]
[  5.00000000e+02   1.26512097e-01]
[  5.00000000e+02   1.26512097e-01]]

[[  1.50000000e+03   1.68693009e-01]
[  1.50000000e+03   1.68693009e-01]
[  1.50000000e+03   1.68693009e-01]
[  1.50000000e+03   1.68693009e-01]
[  1.50000000e+03   1.68693009e-01]
[  1.50000000e+03   1.68693009e-01]
[  1.50000000e+03   1.68693009e-01]
[  1.50000000e+03   1.68693009e-01]
[  1.50000000e+03   1.68693009e-01]]]
```

where is my entry  `a[:,0] == 1000` ? It disappeared. And how can i produce one array like a_sorted[0] = sorted x  and a_sorted[1] = sorted y ?

If i do not transpose `a` prior to argsort, I do get an array of shape (9, 2, 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a.sort(0)
```

sorts your array according to the first column (and keeps the 1000):

```
array([[  5.00000000e+02,   1.22073944e-01],
       [  5.00000000e+02,   1.26512097e-01],
       [  5.00000000e+02,   1.31257631e-01],
       [  5.00000000e+02,   1.32951654e-01],
       [  1.00000000e+03,   1.49342105e-01],
       [  1.50000000e+03,   1.68338907e-01],
       [  1.50000000e+03,   1.68693009e-01],
       [  1.50000000e+03,   1.70665459e-01],
       [  1.50000000e+03,   1.72864036e-01]])
```

If you don't want to sort it in-place, you can use:

```
a[a.argsort(0)[:,0]]
```